# Computer can't detect ubuntu 18.4 from live usb

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu from my USB using multibootusb. Installing Ubuntu into the USB drive was successful and I made sure that my computer boots from the USB first.

I'm booting in UEFI mode because my original OS is Windows 10 and I've made the file format for the drive is FAT32. Even then, the computer goes straight to Windows.

I've even disabled the Windows boot manager but my computer just goes straight to the diagnostic tests. My computer was able to boot Ubuntu after writing it into my USB with Universal USB Installer, so could it be a problem with multiboot?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is not a problem with Ubuntu, it is a problem with your USB/MultibootUSB. Please see [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) instead.

Comment: You can try pressing `esc` button during boot and choose your USB as boot device.